# How to find beacon UUID dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to find beacon's UUID dynamically please help me to find out the solution

Comment: i hope your  UUID dynamically [solution hear.]


  --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248570/dynamic-ibeacons-and-manual-input-of-uuids

Answer (score 0):

if you have macbook visit this site https://github.com/liamnichols/iBeaconScanner and download it sample project.After open and run this project on your macbook. It scans all ibeacon devices near you. It shows DeviceUUID, ProximityUUID, major ,minor, power, RSSI, Distance etc. If it doesn't find your beacon change "scan duration" on app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i need for iOS not for MAC OS